# Delete an s3 object from S3 bucket if an item from source_list exists in target_list

Tags: boto3

I am trying to delete an s3 object from the S3 bucket if an item from source_list exists in target_list.

source_list:

```
['ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_9.json',
'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_10.json']
```

target_list:

```
['ALH-LXN-RESPONSE.json',
 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_1.json',
  'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_2.json',
 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_3.json',
 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_4.json',
 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_5.json',
 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_6.json',
 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_7.json',
 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_8.json',
 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_9.json',
 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_10.json']
```

In this case I need to delete 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_9.json',
'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_10.json'.

```
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket("dw-duwr-84829492409")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code

```
def delete_objects_from_S3():

    source_list = ['ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_9.json', 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_10.json']
    target_list = ['ALH-LXN-RESPONSE.json', 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_1.json', 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_2.json',
                   'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_3.json', 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_9.json', 'ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_10.json']

    commonObjects = [e for e in source_list if e in '\n'.join(target_list)]

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    for item in commonObjects:
        s3.Object('your_bucketName', item).delete()
```